# Mozila pdf.js download pdf using post

Tags: pdf.js

I am using latest build of "pdf.js". Is there a way to load a document with POST instead of GET?

if you can show me the part of the code which is doing the GET call, then I can modify the source code to post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pdfjs has constructors to pass in the data instead as an alternative to the url.   I'd recommend you do a traditional Ajax get to collect your data and pass those bytes to pdfjs, rather than trying to edit pdfjs library.

You need to get (Ajax) the binary data and pass it in

See example here of using the binary data and just needs to be part of your Ajax success parameter.

https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/examples

Comment: Edited just now